# Etcher USB Bootable

Tags: live-usb, etcher

I'm about to run a USB bootable Windows using Etcher on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I'm receiving a warning from Etcher.

Is there a fix for this or any alternative to get this done?

Comment: It won't work. Currently the only tools that works with the new Microsoft ISOs is MKUSB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Windows in a"Live-CD", then you might have better luck with Rufus USB: https://rufus.akeo.ie/ I remember there being an option for Windows To-Go, which is what it sounds like you want. you will need a valid Windows iso and a USB, but it should work. one thing to remember is, Windows isn't meant to be run in this live CD mode, so you will probably need to change the disk label from REMOVABLE to FIXED. I don't remember how to do this, but I think that CHDISK or something on Windows can do it. Also, please note that Rufus only works on Windows, so you will need a working windows box if you happen to try this. Good luck!